# CSS Warning Div with icon

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jsp

I created a warning message or div generally that shows when we checkout for domain purchase.

But when I create my own CSS

The lock icon does must show to the left of the text but shows inline.

Comment: You added your icon inline. Make it a separate div, as well as the text.

Comment: `<strong>` is deprecated. Use CSS `font-weight: bold` together with `<span>` instead.

Comment: This is not how SO works. The questions that are posted here are not only for just person who is posting but are for future references for other users. You can not edit the question after getting it solved. You should post a new question instead.

Comment: _Please delete your answer. I thank to you that your answer was right pls delete tour answer Because my question has changed_ --- You are asking me to delete my answer in the suggestion comment. please read how to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left;` to `<i>`

And Mention approx height to occupy space for `<i>`. I have given `height: 100px;` here.

```css
.ftralert{
width:50%;
padding:15px;
margin-bottom:20px;
border:1px solid transparent;
border-radius:0px
font-family:sans-serif;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust:100%
}
.ftralert-warning{
color:#8a6d3b;
background-color:#fcf8e3;
border-color:#faebcc;
font-family:sans-serif;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust:100%
}

.ftralert-warning i {
float:left;
margin-right:30px;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ftralert ftralert-warning">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style="font-size:24px;"></i>
This ORDER FORM is provided in a secure environment and to help protect against fraud your current IP address (<strong>223.187.232.6</strong>) is being logged.
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You added your icon inline. Make it a separate div, as well as the text, and set the divs to inline block with a set width that adds up to 100% (for example, 20% & 80%, adjust to your needs).

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

https://jsfiddle.net/kh2yn0xa/6/

```css
.ftralert{
padding:15px;
margin-bottom:20px;
border:1px solid transparent;
border-radius:0px
font-family:sans-serif;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
/*remove inline gap*/
font-size: 0;
}
.ftralert-warning{
color:#8a6d3b;
background-color:#fcf8e3;
border-color:#faebcc;
font-family:sans-serif;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust:100%
}

.ftralert > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* adjust for your icon */

.ftralert > div:first-child {
  width: 20%;
}

.ftralert > div:last-child {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ftralert ftralert-warning">
  <div>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style="font-size:24px;">Icon</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    This ORDER FORM is provided in a secure environment and to help protect against fraud your current IP address (<strong>223.187.232.6</strong>) is being logged.
  </div>
</div>
```